# Accessing dynamic object with an invalid name?

Tags: c#, json, dynamic

Using JsonFX I am loading a json stream into my application. The json uses a URL for one of the objects inside, and so, using the default dynamic way of accessing the object doesn't work, as some of the characters in the URL are not valid for a member name.
http://opendatacommunities.org/doc/geography/lsoa/E01004700.json

```
{
   'http://opendatacommunities.org/id/geography/lsoa/E01004700': {
      'http://data.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/ontology/spatialrelations/easting': [
         {
            type: 'literal',
            value: '526252',
            datatype: 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer'
         }
      ],
      'http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#lat': [
         {
            type: 'literal',
            value: '51.51349',
            datatype: 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#decimal'
         }
      ],
      'http://statistics.data.gov.uk/def/administrative-geography/district': [
         {
            type: 'uri',
            value: 'http://statistics.data.gov.uk/id/local-authority-district/00BK'
         }
      ],
      'http://opendatacommunities.org/def/geography#boundaryAsJSON': [
         {
            type: 'uri',
            value: 'http://opendatacommunities.org/lsoa_boundaries/E01004700.json'
         }
      ],
      'http://data.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/ontology/spatialrelations/northing': [
         {
            type: 'literal',
            value: '180964',
            datatype: 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer'
         }
      ],
      'http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#long': [
         {
            type: 'literal',
            value: '-0.18198',
            datatype: 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#decimal'
         }
      ],
      'http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#notation': [
         {
            type: 'literal',
            value: 'E01004700'
         }
      ],
      'http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type': [
         {
            type: 'uri',
            value: 'http://opendatacommunities.org/def/geography#LSOA'
         }
      ],
      'http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label': [
         {
            type: 'literal',
            value: 'Westminster 016E'
         }
      ],
      'http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#sameAs': [
         {
            type: 'uri',
            value: 'http://statistics.data.gov.uk/id/statistical-geography/E01004700'
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Is there a way that I can access this object?

Comment: I can only think to so a quick pre-parse and replace the problem characters with something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the class of mine. Or go to Json.net .

```
 /// <summary>
/// Class Name：JSONConvert
/// Description：JSON Class as JAVA's
/// Authors：ppgame (The deserialization part is by ppgame. The serialization part is from http://www.mzwu.com/)
/// Email: ppgame.mit@gmail.com
/// Date：2012-08-07
/// </summary>
public static class JSONConvert
{
    #region Global Variables
    private static char[] _charary;
    private static int _aryend;

    #endregion

    #region JSON Deserialization

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert string to JSONObject
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="text"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static JSONObject DeserializeSingletonObject(ref int left)
    {
        JSONObject localjson = new JSONObject();
        while (left <= _aryend)
        {
            char c = _charary[left];
            if (c == ' ' || c == '\r' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')  //skip empty char
            {
                left++;
                continue;
            }
            if (c == ',')
            {
                left++;
                continue;
            }
            char r = '\0';
            if (c == '\"' || c == '\'')     //beginning of key
            {
                left++;
                r = c;
            }
            else if (c == '}')      //end of JSONObject
            {
                left++;
                break;
            }
            int column = left;
            while (!((_charary[column] == r || r == '\0') && _charary[column - 1] != '\\' && _charary[column + 1] == ':')) column++;
            if (r == '\0') column++;
            string key = new string(_charary, left, column - left);         //get the key
            if (r == '\0')
                left = column + 1;
            else
                left = column + 2;
            c = _charary[left];
            while (c == ' ' || c == '\r' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')  //skip empty char
            {
                left++;
                c = _charary[left];
            }
            if (c == '\"' || c == '\'')     //if value is string
            {
                left++;
                int strend = left;
                while (_charary[strend] != c || _charary[strend - 1] == '\\') strend++;
                localjson[key] = new string(_charary, left, strend - left);
                left = strend + 1;
            }
            else if (c == '{') // JSONObject
            {
                left++;
                localjson[key] = DeserializeSingletonObject(ref left);
            }
            else if (c == '[')     //JSONArray
            {
                left++;
                localjson[key] = DeserializeSingletonArray(ref left);
            }
            else
            {
                //other class, such as boolean, int
                //all are converted to string, it can be enriched if in need
                int comma = left;
                char co = _charary[comma];
                while (co != ',' && co != '}')
                {
                    comma++;
                    co = _charary[comma];
                }
                int em = comma - 1;
                co = _charary[em];
                while (co == ' ' || co == '\r' || co == '\n' || co == '\t')
                {
                    em--;
                    co = _charary[em];
                }
                localjson[key] = new string(_charary, left, em - left + 1);
                left = comma;
            }
        }
        return localjson;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert string to JSONArray
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="text"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static JSONArray DeserializeSingletonArray(ref int left)
    {
        JSONArray jsary = new JSONArray();
        while (left <= _aryend)
        {
            char c = _charary[left];
            if (c == ' ' || c == '\r' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')  //skip empty char
            {
                left++;
                continue;
            }
            if (c == ',')
            {
                left++;
                continue;
            }
            if (c == ']')
            {
                left++;
                break;
            }
            if (c == '{') //JSONObject
            {
                left++;
                jsary.Add(DeserializeSingletonObject(ref left));
            }
            else if (c == '[')     //JSONArray
            {
                left++;
                jsary.Add(DeserializeSingletonArray(ref left));
            }
            else if (c == '\"' || c == '\'')            //string
            {
                left++;
                int strend = left;
                while (_charary[strend] != c || _charary[strend - 1] == '\\') strend++;
                jsary.Add(new string(_charary, left, strend - left));
                left = strend + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                //other class, such as boolean, int
                //all are converted to string, it can be enriched if in need
                int comma = left;
                char co = _charary[comma];
                while (co != ',' && co != ']')
                {
                    comma++;
                    co = _charary[comma];
                }
                int em = comma - 1;
                co = _charary[em];
                while (co == ' ' || co == '\r' || co == '\n' || co == '\t')
                {
                    em--;
                    co = _charary[em];
                }
                jsary.Add(new string(_charary, left, em - left + 1));
                left = comma;
            }
        }
        return jsary;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Public Interface

    /// <summary>
    /// Get a JSONObject instance from char[]
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="text"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static JSONObject DeserializeCharToObject(char[] input)
    {
        _charary = input;
        _aryend = _charary.Length - 1;
        while (_aryend > 0)
            if (_charary[_aryend] != '}')
                _aryend--;
            else
                break;
        int start = 0;
        while (start < _aryend)
            if (_charary[start] != '{')
                start++;
            else
                break;
        start++;
        if (_aryend < start + 1)
            return null;
        return DeserializeSingletonObject(ref start);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get a JSONObject instance from string
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="text"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static JSONObject DeserializeObject(string input)
    {
        return DeserializeCharToObject(input.ToCharArray());     //The first char must be '{'
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get a JSONArray instance from char[]
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="text"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static JSONArray DeserializeCharsToArray(char[] input)
    {
        _charary = input;
        _aryend = _charary.Length - 1;
        while (_aryend > 0)
            if (_charary[_aryend] != ']')
                _aryend--;
            else
                break;
        int start = 0;
        while (start < _aryend)
            if (_charary[start] != '[')
                start++;
            else
                break;
        start++;
        if (_aryend < start + 1)
            return null;
        return DeserializeSingletonArray(ref start);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get a JSONArray instance from string
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="text"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static JSONArray DeserializeArray(string input)
    {
        return DeserializeCharsToArray(input.ToCharArray());
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Serialize a JSONObject instance
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="jsonObject"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string SerializeObject(JSONObject jsonObject)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("{");
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in jsonObject)
        {
            if (kvp.Value is JSONObject)
            {
                sb.Append(string.Format("\"{0}\":{1},", kvp.Key, SerializeObject((JSONObject)kvp.Value)));
            }
            else if (kvp.Value is JSONArray)
            {
                sb.Append(string.Format("\"{0}\":{1},", kvp.Key, SerializeArray((JSONArray)kvp.Value)));
            }
            else if (kvp.Value is string)
            {
                sb.Append(string.Format("\"{0}\":\"{1}\",", kvp.Key, kvp.Value));
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Append(string.Format("\"{0}\":\"{1}\",", kvp.Key, ""));
            }
        }
        if (sb.Length > 1)
            sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);
        sb.Append("}");
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Serialize a JSONArray instance
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="jsonArray"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string SerializeArray(JSONArray jsonArray)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("[");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.Count; i++)
        {
            if (jsonArray[i] is JSONObject)
            {
                sb.Append(string.Format("{0},", SerializeObject((JSONObject)jsonArray[i])));
            }
            else if (jsonArray[i] is JSONArray)
            {
                sb.Append(string.Format("{0},", SerializeArray((JSONArray)jsonArray[i])));
            }
            else if (jsonArray[i] is string)
            {
                sb.Append(string.Format("\"{0}\",", jsonArray[i]));
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Append(string.Format("\"{0}\",", ""));
            }

        }
        if (sb.Length > 1)
            sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);
        sb.Append("]");
        return sb.ToString();
    }
    #endregion
}

/// <summary>
/// Class Name：JSONObject
/// Description：JSON Class
/// Author：dnawo
/// Website：http://www.mzwu.com/
/// Date：2010-01-06
/// Version：1.1.0
/// </summary>
public class JSONObject : Dictionary<string, object>
{
    public void put(string key, string value)
    {
        this[key] = value;
    }

    public void put(string key, int value)
    {
        this[key] = value.ToString();

    }

}

/// <summary>
/// Class Name：JSONArray
/// Description：JSONArray Class
/// Author：dnawo
/// Website：http://www.mzwu.com/
/// Date：2010-01-06
/// Version：1.1.0
/// </summary>
public class JSONArray : List<object>
{ }
```

Comment: I used the preparse method in the end. Thanks anyway - You might want to change your variable names to fit with convention, as they are currently not clear in any way.